# how to get shared value proportion by each row in r

Tags: r

```
type<-c("111","111","111","222","222","222","222","333","333","333","444","444","444")

location<-c("aaa","bbb","ccc","aaa","bbb","ddd","eee","aaa","ccc","ddd","ccc","ddd","fff")

datafr1 <- data.frame(type,location)
```

I want the result like this.(don't need to be a format like this.)

```
           222     333    444
111      0.66%    0.66%   0.33%
```

and 222, 333, 444 too.
Find the shared values and then get proportion of intersection.

Can you help me?!!

Comment: Are these values correct?  `prop.table(tcrossprod(table(datafr1)), 1)`

Comment: thx for response!. but, between 111 and 111 has to be 1. And between 111 and 222 has to be 2/3 = 0.66%!

Comment: Please check the solution provided below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do a crossproduct on the `table` output of 'datafr1', then divide each row by the maximum value of the output

```
m1 <- tcrossprod(table(datafr1))
m1/matrixStats::rowMaxs(m1)
#      type
#type        111       222       333       444
#  111 1.0000000 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.3333333
#  222 0.5000000 1.0000000 0.5000000 0.2500000
#  333 0.6666667 0.6666667 1.0000000 0.6666667
#  444 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.6666667 1.0000000
```

Comment: oh my godness. I have struggled this in my dream but you solved it... How make that simple function in a minutes....You  are genious...I really appreciate!!!

Comment: I did it and got the results. you are real god..!

Comment: @이승준  Thanks for the comments.  I am just another guy who like programming.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only using `data.table` for the `rbindlist` at the end. You could replace this with a `do.call` on `rbind` or something similar if you don't want to use `data.table`.

```
typevals <- unique(datafr1$type)

funky <- function(typeval) {
  uniqueloc <- unique(datafr1[type == typeval,]$location)
  props <- sapply(typevals, 
                  function(x) {
                    length(intersect(uniqueloc, datafr1[type == x,]$location))/length(uniqueloc)
                  })
  props <- round(props, 2)
  df <- data.frame(t(props))
  names(df) <- typevals
  df <- cbind(data.frame(type = typeval), df)
}
rbindlist(lapply(typevals, funky))
#    type  111  222  333  444
# 1:  111 1.00 0.67 0.67 0.33
# 2:  222 0.50 1.00 0.50 0.25
# 3:  333 0.67 0.67 1.00 0.67
# 4:  444 0.33 0.33 0.67 1.00
```

Comment: omg its awesome..how you guys think those function.. I just astonished and got shocked...I really appreciate. I struggled over 12 hours, however you guys solved in a minutes...!!